# Batch reading xlsx-file with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to read xlsx-file with Apache POI & I need to do it with batches (e.g. reading 100 rows of sheet -> saving to database, reading next 100 rows -> saving to database & so on).

Please tell me how to realise it with Apache POI (desirable with example). If it unreal, please, advise me library to perform it.

Comment: it is possible, but we are no code writing community. You can come to us if you have a problem with existing code but we wont do all your work for you

Comment: Using spring batch also you can do .first you need to split the file and insert into DB.